# Azure usage api return invalid meter id (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

Tags: api, azure, meter

when I call azure usage api below, azure returned invalid meterid like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

I couldn't find reference like this so our billing batch failed everyday 
what is the mean for meterid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ??

1. published azure api

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2017-11-11&reportedEndTime=2017-11-12&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false

2. returned invalid value list (it's part of value)

> "meterId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","quantity":0.001,"subscriptionId":"e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa","usageEndTime":"2017-11-12T00:00:00+00:00","usageStartTime":"2017-11-11T00:00:00+00:00"},"type":"Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregate"},{"id":"/subscriptions/e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/Daily_BRSDT_20171111_0000","name":"Daily_BRSDT_20171111_0000","properties":{"infoFields":{},"instanceData":"{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"/subscriptions/e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa/resourceGroups/rsgroup02/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/rsgroup02diag930\",\"location\":\"jaeast\"}}","meterCategory":"Data Management"
>
> "meterId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","quantity":6.0E-4,"subscriptionId":"e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa","usageEndTime":"2017-11-12T00:00:00+00:00","usageStartTime":"2017-11-11T00:00:00+00:00"},"type":"Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregate"},{"id":"/subscriptions/e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/Daily_BRSDT_20171111_0000","name":"Daily_BRSDT_20171111_0000","properties":{"infoFields":{},"instanceData":"{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"/subscriptions/e2850eff-22cd-4c21-8418-12703b5631aa/resourceGroups/rsgroup02/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/rsgroup02diag930\",\"location\":\"jaeast\"}}","meterCategory":"Data Management"